# AngularJS UI router child states not waiting for parent resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Seems like child states are not waiting till parent state resolved. I am using resolve config option to load common data soon after user login to the system in a common parent state. Then all children can use it. Also I have a auth interceptor to check data has been loaded. I have created a simple example to demonstrate my problem. You don't need a username or a password to login and just see the logs. Application not navigate you to the home page because user data hasn't been loaded. I used one of a examples found in http://scotch.io to create this simple app. I wonder how to configure ui router, to child states wait till parents promises are resolved.

When authorize fires for app.home state on $stateChangeStart even data has not been loaded even I am loading data in app state which is the parent for app.home

```
function authorize(event, toState, toParams){
        if(/^app/.test(toState.name)) {
            console.log('toState', toState, 'cache', cache);
            if(!cache.hasOwnProperty('user')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.transitionTo('login');
                console.log('data not loaded', event);
            }
        }
    }
```

Example

http://plnkr.co/edit/hS8jKONk0ZfyJfE4r7Ty?p=preview